# passing UTM parameters into a web-page content

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, utm

I am using a tracking software (Voluum) that generates for me campaign URLs with UTM parameters. Is there a way how I could pass the data from my UTM parameters and display it as a dynamic content on a web-page?

For example a visitor accesses **domain.com/?city={city}** where the **{city}** in his case is **Berlin**. is it possible to show him the word "Berlin" on the web-page right during his first visit?

thank you!

Comment: sure `echo htmlentities($_GET['city']);`

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do this:

1. On the **server side**, if your server supports PHP, Python... or any server side language that can dynamically

In PHP you can retrieve the variable using the $_GET array.

```
$_GET['city']
```

2. On the **client side**, using JavaScript

Here is a function that retrieves the variable 'name' from the URL

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
document.write(getURLParameter('city'))
```